# node-memwatch on node 4+?

Tags: node.js, node-memwatch

Anyone know if node-memwatch supports newer versions of node (4+)? I get lots of install errors on node 4.2.2 (starting with:

> make: Entering directory `/home/joni/inpact/sources/ros/node_modules/memwatch/build'
>     CXX(target) Release/obj.target/memwatch/src/heapdiff.o
>   In file included from ../src/heapdiff.cc:5:0:
>   ../src/heapdiff.hh:15:5: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
>        {
>        ^
>   ../src/heapdiff.hh:19:49: error: ‘Arguments’ in namespace ‘v8’ does not name a type
>            static v8::Handle New( const v8::Arguments& args );

...)

I checked out their build [on travis-ci](https://travis-ci.org/lloyd/node-memwatch/builds) and it looks like they're only building on node 0.1, 0.6 and 0.8.

Just wondering if anyone has gotten this working on later versions of node.